# Sending MHT file using C# Mail Message

Tags: c#

Has anyone got any sample code to send [MHT](http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/MHT-MHTML-document-Microsoft) using SmtpClient and MailMessage in C#?

I have found tantalising references to using [Alternate Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx) but I cannot figure out how to make this work with my SSRS generated MHT.

If anyone has any working code they are willing to share I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: You can create reports and subscritions to delivery those reports via email in multiple formats included MHTML. Configure SMTP Settings in SSRS, check [this](http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/email-configuration-in-ssrs-with-smtp-in-windows-server-2008r2/). In subscription select MHTML format.

Comment: I already have a MHTML document that I need to send. Don't want SSRS to do it as I have other requirements. Need to do it from C# code.

Comment: Do you want to attach or embed the MHTML file in mail body? I think [this](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/loadMhtmlAndSendEmail.asp) code can help you. Also keep in mind embedded MHTML in mails can be shown unformatted due to client mail block and support for MIME.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta I want to embed it in the body. That code sample uses an external commercial library "Chilkat" to that. I either want something native or open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears that .NET MailMessage does not support this out of the box. I have found a couple of approaches that can be used with varying degrees of success.

**MHTML -> HTML Decoder**

David Benko wrote https://github.com/DavidBenko/MHTML-to-HTML-Decoding-in-C-Sharp/blob/master/MHTMLParser.cs and while it works, I was unable to make the images appear when I viewed the resulting email. The HTML looked right, it just did not work in Outlook 2010.

**Convert MimeKit MimeMessage to .NET Mail Message**

As Jeffrey points out this is a start https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/issues/140. I had problems again with the images not being displayed in the resulting message.

**Use MimeKit & MailKit**

I ended up using https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit to do the job. This can be achieved as follows:

```
   MimeMessage messageMimeKit = MimeMessage.Load(Request.MapPath("~/Blah/378921.mht"));

   messageMimeKit.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Dev", "developer@gmail.com"));
   messageMimeKit.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Homer", "homer@gmail.com"));
   messageMimeKit.Subject = "Another subject line";
   using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient()) 
   {
      client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
      client.Authenticate("homer@gmail.com", "*****");
      client.Send(messageMimeKit);
      client.Disconnect(true);
   }
```

Comment: Best to link https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit instead of MimeKit. Since Mailkit has a dependency on it, and it is used to send the email.

Answer (score 1):

**Using System.Net.Http.Formatting**

My approach leverages the [ReadAsMultipartAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh944544(v%3Dvs.118)) extension methods on HttpContent found in the System.Net.Http.Formatting library. (part of the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) nuget package)

The only tricky bit is getting the correct content type out of the file.  In order for the ReadAsMultipartAsync method to work, it needs the ContentType header on the stream content set to the correct type ("multipart/related"), including the correct boundary parameter on the content type value:

```
multipart/related;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_01C35DB7.4B204430"
```

Please note, since my solution was only written for sending content from SSRS reports exported in the MTHML format, my code assumes the multipart content has only one text/html part with the remaining parts being images, but the technique is sound and could be adjusted to handle multipart content in a more generic way.

```
const string ContentTypePrefix = "Content-Type: ";

AlternateView htmlView = null;
var linkedResources = new List<LinkedResource>();

var content = File.ReadAllText("report.mhtml");
var startIndex = content.IndexOf(ContentTypePrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + ContentTypePrefix.Length;
var endIndex = content.IndexOf("\"", startIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
var contentType = content.Substring(startIndex, endIndex);
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
{
    using (var stream = new StreamContent(memoryStream))
    {
        stream.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(contentType);
        if (!stream.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new Exception("Not correct format.");
        }
        var parts = stream.ReadAsMultipartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        foreach (var part in parts.Contents)
        {
            part.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = part.Headers.ContentType.CharSet?.Replace("\"", string.Empty); // Needed since the SSRS report defaults the charset to \"utf-8\", instead of utf-8 and the code fails to find the correct encoder
            var compressedContent = part.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (!part.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.Contains("image"))
            {
                var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(part.Headers.ContentType.CharSet);
                var partContent = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(compressedContent));
                htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(partContent, encoding, part.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);
            }
            else
            {
                linkedResources.Add(new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(compressedContent)), part.Headers.ContentType.MediaType)
                {
                    ContentId = part.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty)
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach (var linkedResource in linkedResources)
{
    htmlView?.LinkedResources.Add(linkedResource);
}

using (var message = new MailMessage("from@mail.com", "to@mail.com", "Subject", string.Empty))
{
    message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
    using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtpserver.com", 25))
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```